# My Controller is not working i dont know what is problum

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I don't know my controller is not working .

I m create a controller but is not working .
I know it's little mistake but i m see many times but now show .

Please Help me .

**Angular Code**

```
var myPanelSearch = angular.module('left-panel-search', []);
    myPanelSearch.controller=('leftPanelSearch', function($scope){
        $scope.msm = "Wincere";
    });
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body ng-app="left-panel-search">
  <div ng-controller="leftPanelSearch">
    {{msm}} {{5+2}}
  </div>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAeG4suTB3YcoIb2mbk6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `=` sign after `myPanelSearch.controller`, it should be a method invocation, not assignment:

```
myPanelSearch.controller('leftPanelSearch', function($scope) {
    $scope.msm = "Wincere";
});
```

Also you would have spotted the error if you kept developer console open.

Fixed [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UtHntSIkGc88ziDQuFsg?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the = AFTER controller

```
   .controller()
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8zz7qCu8ZEPn5YMPySX?p=preview